# Steinberg's Nuendo 4 Video Subtitles

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audacity

I am using Steinberg's Nuendo 4 to edit audio tracks in an H264 MP4 video, and I would like to show the subtitles in the Nuendo local video player.

Nuendo 4 doesn't seem to have import subtitles option, I tried to burn the subtitles directly into the video using tools like FFMPEG or VidCoder, but then working with the result video in Nuendo starts to have strange issues like you cannot navigate smoothly between the timecodes.

Does anyone know a better way or practice to handle the subtitles inside Nuendo 4 when my target video is H264 MP4?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best approach to solve this particular issue, but I solved the problem by re-exporting the video with the burned subtitles using Media Encoder and a custom preset